Expert misidentifies venomous snake as non venomous
I'm a member of a snake identification group on social media and they recently had a conversation about potential liability for misidentified snakes.  This group takes identification very seriously to where only the admins and certain experts can identify snakes and once a snake is identified the comments are closed so nobody else can post potentially wrong information that could cause confusion.  I say this because they both explicitly claim and have a reputation of being experts that do not guess a snake's identification, instead if they identify a snake that is the correct identification.
However in reality, very rarely a wrong identification slips through and is approved by an admin who closes comments preventing further correction of the ID.  This has even happened where venomous snakes are misidentified as "harmless" species. (yes they almost always use the word harmless to identify any non venomous species).  Additionally the group frequently makes it a point to note that non venomous snake bites are highly unlikely to cause disease or infection since cold blooded animals do not carry many disease/bacteria that can affect humans.
In such an instance where a person posts a picture of a venomous snake, gets an ID claiming it to be harmless, and then is bitten trying to remove the snake from their home would the identifier/admin of the group face any potential liability?

Someone in the discussion of liability said it would be assumed risk (which is probably true) and no different than slipping on clearly icy stairs.  However the average person knows very little about snakes and if an expert tells you it's safe to pick up you couldn't be expected to have "known better".   I'm quite certain if you were in person with a "snake expert" and they told you to pick up a venomous snake they would definitely be liable so does the fact that it happened over the internet change that?  The average person should definitely be aware that the internet is a cesspool of misinformation but as stated this group really aggressively markets itself as being free of that, and for the most part it really is in practice.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
